# Export Parametric Plot as PNG with no background

Tags: graphics, export, png-format, plotting

How do I export a ParametricPlot as a png image with no background?  For example, my exported image look like this:

[image]

But it has a white background.  I need that white background to be a completely transparent alpha channel, but I cannot figure out how to do this with ParametricPlot.  Can somebody give an example using the `Export` command?

Comment: The easiest way is to do `Export["test.png",Rasterize[yourplot,Background->None]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `Background -> None` inside `Export` . Assume that you have a parametric plot

`a = ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]` .

`Export["tra.png", a, Background -> None]` .